# Kivy 1.10.1 how can I change something's font_size using options settings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently trying to create an options menu that may change the text size of specific blocks of text in my application. I basically want to have three different options for the user to pick between.

I've tried adapting the code in kivy-examples which lets you change font_size using  a numeric value to instead change the font size using options. But I can't get it to work so I'm sort of stuck.

Here's my app class

```
class MainApp(App):

def build(self):
    self.settings_cls = SettingsWithTabbedPanel

    root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
    label = root.ids.label
    label.font_size = float(self.config.get('example', 'typesize'))
    return root
def build_config(self, config):
    config.setdefaults('example', {
        'typesize': 'Default'})
def build_settings(self, settings):
    settings.add_json_panel('Settings', self.config, data=settings_json)

def on_config_change(self,config,section,key,value):

    Logger.info("main.py: App.on_config_change: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(
        config, section, key, value))

    if section == 'example':
        if key == 'typesize':
            if value == 'Small':
                self.root.ids.label.font_size = '12pt'

            elif value == 'Default':
                self.root.ids.label.font_size = '20pt'

            elif value == 'Large':
                self.root.ids.label.font_size = '40pt' 
def close_settings(self, settings=None):
    """
    The settings panel has been closed.
    """
    Logger.info("main.py: App.close_settings: {0}".format(settings))
    super(MyApp, self).close_settings(settings)
```

and here is the bit of kivy language I'm trying to affect using this (it's in a different document). (the indentation looks a bit strange here but that's some wonkiness when I copied it into here)

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'horizontal'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: .5
        orientation:'horizontal'
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                id:label
                text: ' some really really long string ' * 100
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
```

and here's my json code (in a separate document as well) because I may want to create more settings.

```
import json

settings_json = json.dumps([

    {'type': 'options',
     'title': 'Text size',
     'desc': 'Change the size of text in the application',
     'section': 'example',
     'key': 'typesize',
     'options': ['Small', 'Default', 'Large']}])
```

When I try to run my program right now immidietly crashes/doesn't start.